# Set iterator invalidated by move semantic

Tags: c++, iterator, move-semantics

I have the following immutable container class (public access to `values` is just for reasons of simplicity):

```
struct Container
{
    std::unordered_set<int> values;

    //Default constructor
    Container() = default;

    //Copy constructor
    Container(const Container& other)
        : values(other.values)
    {   }

    //Move constructor
    Container(const Container&& other)
        : values(std::move(other.values))
    {   }

    Container RemoveValue(int value) const
    {
        //Create a copy of this object
        Container copy(*this);
        //Remove one element from the copy
        copy.values.erase(value);
        return copy;
    }
};
```

This container contains a set of values. The method `RemoveValue()` returns a copy of the current object where a specific value has been removed. An appropriate move constructor is defined for this struct.

I use this container as follows:

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<Container> containers;

    {
        //Initialization
        Container initialContainer;
        initialContainer.values.insert(1);
        initialContainer.values.insert(2);

        containers.push_back(std::move(initialContainer));
    }

    const Container* currentContainer = &containers.front();
    for (int value : currentContainer->values)
    {
        Container newContainer = currentContainer->RemoveValue(value);

        //Do some checks, then...
        containers.push_back(std::move(newContainer));
    }

    std::cout << containers.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I initialize a vector of containers with a single container (with values 1 and 2). Then, I acquire a pointer to this initial element and iterate every value. For each value, I call `RemoveValue()` and insert the resulting container into the vector.

In gcc, this seems to work just fine. However, I get runtime errors in Visual Studio 2015.

In Debug Mode, the error is: **"list iterator not incrementable"**. This error occurs after the first iteration at `for (int value : currentContainer->values)` (when the iterator is to be incremented).

In Release Mode, the error is: **"Access violation reading at position 0x38"**. This error occurs at `copy.values.erase(value)` in `RemoveValue`. But only in the second iteration. Surprisingly, `values` does not contain elements at this point, anymore (`size()` returns 0).

I don't understand either of these errors. How can I resolve them?

[A C++ Shell example](http://cpp.sh/6eraw) also runs without errors. However, it outputs `2` as the final number of containers, whereas I expected three (the initial one, one with `1` removed, one with `2` removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentContainer` is a pointer to an element of the vector `containers`. The loop body modifies `containers` by calling `push_back`. That can invalidate pointers into the vector, and if it does, `currentContainer` can end up pointing to garbage.

In general, don't use pointers to objects that are held in an `std::vector`. Instead, use `containers.front()` or `containers[0]` to get at the first element.